# How do I troubleshoot git submodule add https:// fatal: Authentication failed for

Tags: git, bitbucket

I was unable to add a submodule to my repository. I can checkout and checkin code to repository.

```
git submodule add https://....git
Cloning into 'C:/code/bitbucket/Repos/...'...
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https:....git/'
fatal: clone of 'https://....git' into submodule path 'C:/code/bitbucket/Repos/...' failed
```

Comment: I mean...it says "authentication failed". Do you have appropriate credentials? Are you able to clone that repository directly (i.e. using `git clone` rather than adding it as a submodule)?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to clone and update submodule repo.

```
git submodule add **ssh://**....git
```

Not sure why.